# zoom in/out a picture by scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, uiscrollview, zooming

I need to zoom in/out a picture, when I'm scrolling on that picture.
I'm asking you only about how to detect scroll in/out on the picture? I'm trying this (I've found it in the internet):

```
$('.map').scroll(function(event){
              if(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
                alert('scrolling up !');
              }
             else{
               alert('scrolling down !');
              }
            });
```

//

```
 .map
```

is the class of my picture.

It doesn't work for me ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Attach `mousewheel` event as `scroll` event is sent whenever the element's scroll position changes.

```js
$('#map').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
    console.log('scrolling up !', 'X: ', e.pageX, 'Y: ', e.pageY);
  } else {
    console.log('scrolling down !', 'X: ', e.pageX, 'Y: ', e.pageY);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xft1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/13096358_986500121418450_5109646388299684610_n.jpg?oh=27ee2801d2df5c9426eef38bb8a45509&oe=57DF3F79&__gda__=1474329392_83b88030c94ec8611160c14161311db5" id="map">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: May I detect a position of cursor like this:   `var mouseX = event.pageX; var mouseY = event.pageY; `?

Comment: It's perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of plugin, one is: [wheelzoom on GitHub](https://github.com/jackmoore/wheelzoom/tree/master):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  wheelzoom(document.getElementById('map'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jackmoore/wheelzoom/master/wheelzoom.js"></script>

<img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xft1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/13096358_986500121418450_5109646388299684610_n.jpg?oh=27ee2801d2df5c9426eef38bb8a45509&oe=57DF3F79&__gda__=1474329392_83b88030c94ec8611160c14161311db5" id="map">
```

Comment: It's a good thing, but I should write it by myself :) I've been given an answer )